# sql developer data export date format is null

Tags: sql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL developer connected to a db2 database.

I want to export a table to a list of insert statements. This works, but the problem is that dates are shown like:

```
to_timestamp('2016-02-08 11:07:54.01','null'),
```

There is no date format specified, so executing insert statements like this doesn't work.

I did set the date format in Preferences->Database->NLS
for 'Date format','Timestamp format' and 'Timestamp TZ format' to:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3
```

But somehow SQL developer keeps spitting out null values. Is there some other setting I need to check?

Comment: The format string isn't required, so you could remove the parameter altogether.  Otherwise, this looks like an application bug, given that the string `'null'` (or even the actual `null` value, which is different) isn't valid input for any of the related functions I'm aware of.

Comment: yeah, the output doens't make much sense, but it is added by the export wizzard. My guess is it tries to load or parse some config parameter. Haven't found it yet, so this could be a bug